# Time complexity of checking tweaked identical binary trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, big-o, time-complexity

I came cross a problem on an online judge as follows:

Check two given binary trees are identical or not. Assuming any number of tweaks are allowed. A tweak is defined as a swap of the children of one node in the tree.

[image]

I came up with the following naive algorithm which was accepted.

```
/**
 * @aaram a, b, the root of binary trees.
 * @return true if they are tweaked identical, or false.
 */
bool isTweakedIdentical(TreeNode* a, TreeNode* b) {
    if (!a || !b)
        return !a && !b;
    return a->val == b->val && 
    ((isTweakedIdentical(a->left, b->left) && isTweakedIdentical(a->right, b->right)) ||
    (isTweakedIdentical(a->left, b->right) && isTweakedIdentical(a->right, b->left)));
}
```

However, I can't figure out the time complexity of my solution. Can anyone teach me how to analyze it? I'm not sure when worst case happens.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how "binary" you expect the tree to be.

If the trees constructed tend to be more linearly chained, then your algorithm will tend to perform linearly, `O(N)` (with N non-tail-call recursions which could potentially lead to stack overflow with large trees).

If your trees constructed tend to be more binary, as in both children have roughly equal tree sizes at each node, then your algorithm will perform <s>logarithmically</s> quadratically, <s>`O(log2(N))`</s> `O(N^2)`.

Your worst case is when `a` is linear down the right side, and `b` is linear down the left side. You could improve your average case by pseudorandomly choosing which paths to check first, but at the cost of a call to `rand()` for each call to your function. I don't know that it would be worth the cost, but it's just a suggestion.

**EDIT**

Consider this example for binary trees:

```
       _1_
      /   \
    _2     3_
   / |     | \
  4  5     6  7
 /|  |\   /|  |\
8 9  A B C D  E F

       _1_
      /   \
    _3     2_
   / |     | \
  7  6     5  4
 /|  |\   /|  |\
F E  D C B A  9 8
```

These are two examples of [`heaps`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). And they match, except they're mirrored. This would take 43 calls to `isTweakedIdentical()` in order to return `true`. But this seems to be an `O(N)` operation, considering it averages 3 calls per node (except for the root). I'll finish editing this later.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if that `return` statement counts as "tail-call recursion" or not... feedback?

Comment: I believe it is O((n1+n2)^2) when two input trees are balanced, because of the recurrence relation T(n1+n2) = 4 * T((n1+n2)/2) + O(1), which says that to check if two trees A and B of size n1 and n2 are tweaked-identical, we need to check four subproblems, namely, (1) A's left subtree is tweaked-identical to B's left subtree, (2) A's right subtree is tweaked-identical to B's right subtree, (3) A's left subtree is tweaked-identical to B's right subtree, and (4) A's right subtree is tweaked-identical to B's left subtree. Also, we do constant amount of work at each recursion step.

Comment: @Zilong it's not a constant amount of work at each recursion step, due to logical short-circuiting.

Comment: Hence I don't think your logarithmical argument about balanced trees is correct. But I don't know when the worst case happens. It should be at least quadratic. Am I right?

Comment: Why isn't it constant amount of work? Could you explain it more? Even without short-circuiting, it's constant amount of work. All it does is to perform a few boolean operations over the results of subproblems.

Comment: @Zilong I actually hadn't considered that case until just now. Now I believe that for balanced trees, it's `O(N^2)` worst case scenario, but that's only true if the diff is at one of the deepest recursion calls. And it's not constant because the amount of checks required is less if `a->left` and `b->left` and `a->right` and `b->right` match.

Comment: I'd imagine that a heap like this is actually a really good case for the algorithm, since any time there's a mismatch in the path taken the algorithm will short-circuit. I'd figure a tree with all values same except one at the leaf is a much more realistic worst-case.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, let's imagine that you're working with a perfect binary tree with n nodes in it. At each level, you fire off at most four recursive calls, each to a binary tree that has (roughly) n / 2 nodes in it. You're doing O(1) work per call, so we get the recurrence relation

> T(n) ≤ 4T(n / 2) + O(1)

Using the Master Theorem, we're in a case where a = 4, b = 2, and d = 0, and since log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>2</sub> 4 = 2 and d = 0, we see that the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup>) in this case.

The problem with this upper bound is that it's not tight. In particular, looking at the structure of the recursive calls that get made, we only get four recursive calls if no short-circuiting exists. That would require the first call in each of the two cases to return true and the second branch to return false. I've spent the last half hour trying to craft a worst-case tree and prove that it's a worst-case tree, but I'm having a heck of a time doing so. I suspect that the answer is somewhere between O(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub> 3</sup>), which is what you get at three calls per node, and O(n<sup>2</sup>), but I'm not certain about it. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I agree with your argument on balanced binary trees. However, I think it doesn't provide an upper bound, because the input may not be balanced. So we don't know if balanced binary trees are the worst case. Am I right?

Comment: I feel like balanced binary trees where the diff is in the last place checked would be the worst case at `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @Zilong I actually think imbalanced trees are a great case for you, since if the tree is imbalanced, a lot of the recursive calls will start to fail once you walk off the tree somewhere. As an extreme case, degenerate linked list trees will be processed in time O(n) in the worst case, since every call that doesn't go the right way instantly fails.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I suspect that you're right, but since multiple calls revisit the same tree repeatedly what would be visited last in one case might be visited first in another. Perhaps I"m overthinking it, though.